# In DNS, how do I delegate just the zone apex to a different nameserver?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, delegation

I have a domain with two completely distinct backends, as follows:

- The zone apex (example.com) serves a CloudFront distribution
- All other subdomains (*.example.com) point to a load balancer with an application behind it. There are thousands of subdomains.

I have a non-AWS primary DNS provider for the domain (which I'm very happy with), however since I'm not able to use a CNAME on my zone apex I'm using the provider's ALIAS record implementation to point to CloudFront at the apex. Given the implementation of that ALIAS record, I'm often receiving a CloudFront PoP that is not closest to me, and the latency is not optimal.

My thought was to delegate DNS resolution of just the zone apex (example.com) to Route 53, while keeping all other subdomains under the responsibility of my current DNS provider.

Is delegating **just** the zone apex to a different DNS provider even possible? and if so, how can that be done?

Comment: you can only set one authoritiv dns at domain level and one ore more secondaries. for my self i host all on my own and dont have to think about it ;) but this decission has its pro and contra

Comment: "My thought was to delegate DNS resolution of just the zone apex (example.com) " The DNS does not work like that. As soon as you delegate a part of the tree, everything below that node is handled by the nameservers you delegateds to. You should instead keep the apex and delegate a subtree to other nameservers.